# ClamAV Database Usage Policy?

Tags: gpl

What about if I sell computers with embedded home-made antivirus using ClamAV database as its main database or as optional database? Of course the software isn't open-source/GPL.

Is it allowed?

Many thanks.

Comment: What licese terms are on the database? If the data is only GPL licensed, you're probably fine: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218344/can-i-use-gpl-code-as-textual-data-in-my-app/218348#218348 If the data has more restrictive terms, you may not be.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a conceptual programming question.  Note that the ClamAV home page says "ClamAV is an open source antivirus engine," so your claim that it's not open source appears to be wrong.

Comment: i think the license type is GPL v2, still fine?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I mean my "home-made antivirus" is not an open source.

Comment: Then you can't do it.  If you're trying to borrow components from ClamAV, your entire antivirus program must be GPL v2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can read the database without using GPL code (borrowed from ClamAV or obtained elsewhere), and if the license of the database itself allows it, then you can use the database as input for your non-free application.

If you can't read the database without using GPL code, then that GPL code forces you to release your application under the GPL as well.

In general, an application and the data it uses are considered separate unrelated works under copyright law, so their licenses generally don't affect each other and don't need to be compatible.
For that reason, the license on the ClamAV *database* can be very different and much more restrictive than the license on the ClamAV *application*. If you want to use the database, be sure to check under what terms it is being distributed.

Comment: The license on ClamAV database is GPLv2. To read the database, I use DLL file which is also GPL.

Comment: @KompasAntivirus: The DLL you use to read the database will be a deal breaker for creating a non-GPL application.

Comment: "I'll also note that you can not 'link' to GPL 
code via a non-GPL'd app unless 1) the library is LGPL'd, or 2) You have 
an exception made by the developers of said app" taken from http://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-win32/2008-August/000592.html

Comment: @KompasAntivirus: That is correct, and a DLL also gets linked into your application (be it at runtime). See also the last paragraph in the mailing-list post you referenced.